# Prisma: get name of active Postgresql schema for the connection

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I run tests with a test environment where migrations are run against a randomly named Postgresql schema. However, it is hard to test APIs using queryRaw because those queries do not run against the right schema, apparently..? Is there a Prisma method for "get name of the Postgresql schema used for this connection"?

Comment: Can you try appending the schema name in front of the table name in queryRaw?
It could look something like this:
await prisma.$queryRaw(`SELECT * FROM "${schemaName}".tableName`);

Comment: That's my plan, but to do that I need to know what the randomly generated schema name actually is. So I was hoping Prisma would have an API to tell me..

Comment: There isn't an API to get the randomly generated schema but you can run this query to get the current schema, store it in a variable and then use it in the next raw query: `const result = await prisma.$queryRaw(`SELECT current_schema()`);`

Comment: @NurulSundarani thank you! I suggest you add this as an answer (not a comment) so that I can accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, there is no API to get the randomly generated schema but you can use `current_schema()` function to get the current schema, store it in a variable and then use it in the subsequent raw query:

```js
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client';

const schema = await prisma.$queryRaw(`SELECT current_schema()`);

await prisma.$queryRaw(`SELECT * FROM "${Prisma.raw(schema)}".tableName`);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it helped :) In case anyone else has the same problem, I amended your example code slightly and added a `Prisma.raw()` call to make Prisma not use schema as a substitution value, since Postgres does not accept that..